# Create a timeline in rails / html / js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a Rails app that has events in it, and I'd like to be able to show a timeline of events. There's an Event model, and events have a `start_date` and `end_date`.

I can show the events by date etc without any problem. However, what I'd like to be able to do is create a horizontal "timeline", similar to the network graph on Github. Basically I'd like to be able to plot a graph with lines from the start date to the end date, and for any given set of events I'd like the timeline on the top to start with the date of the earliest event and then span horizontally in even increments of time to the end date of the last event.

How would you accomplish something like that in HTML / JS? I believe I understand the server side of things enough to pull any needed data from the app, what I don't understand is how to make a view out of it. To be honest I'm not even sure where to start.

I really appreciate any feedback or suggestions on how to get started in tackling this. I realize this question is more open-ended than ideal, I'll be happy to try and make it more specific in response to comments.

Answer (score 0):

try [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar), you may see some screen shots [here](http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/7/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin) and this is the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars)

HTH :)